# PHP script downloads PDFs but not images located outside the root

Tags: php, image, file, pdf, download

My PHP script has difficulty downloading PNG and JPG images from a folder outside of the root, the files become corrupted somehow. PDF files, on the other hand, can be downloaded without issues. I have confirmed that the files exist, have the correct MIME types (`image/png` and `image/jpeg`), and are not empty (file size not zero).

The files also exist in the uploads folder, and I can open them with preview tools, etc., so the file in the server works as intended, and I suspect I set my headers wrong.

The file download gets triggered when the file is clicked that starts a page load with GET parameters (I'm using a front controller)

```js
container.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // ... Get the user id and file name ...

    // Construct the URL to the PHP script that gets the correct file
    const open = `/view/?user=${user}&file=${file}&open=true`;

    // Open in a new page (used for inline, not attachments)
    window.open(open, '_blank');
});
```

My view file:

```php
// Make sure the user is authenticated...

// If download, user, and file parameters are set, download the file:
if(isset($_GET['open']) && isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['file'])){
    if(!Files::open($_GET['file'], $_GET['user'])){
        Report::error("Error");
    }

    Report::success("Success");
    exit();
}
```

My `Files::open()` function:

```php
/**
 * Open a requested file.
 * 
 * @param string $file
 * The file to open.
 * 
 * @param string $folder
 * The folder where the file is located.
 * 
 * @return bool
 * True if the file was opened successfully, false otherwise.
 */
public static function open(string $file, string $folder = ''): bool {

    // Update: 16.05.2023 - Quickfix for vulnerability:
    $file = str_replace(['../', '..\\'], '', $file);

    // Path to the file, this currently only picks
    // files from the uploads folder:
    $path = dirname(__DIR__, 2) . "/uploads/$folder/$file";
    Report::notice("Opening the file '$file' from the '$folder' folder.");

    // If the file does not exist, return false:
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        Report::warning("The file '$file' does not exist in the '$folder' folder.");
        return false;
    }

    // Create a new Fileinfo object:
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    // Get the mime type:
    $mime = $finfo->file($path);

    // Get the mime type:
    Report::notice("The mime type of the file '$file' is '$mime'.");

    // Set the headers (usually inline, attachment for testing):
    header("Content-Type: $mime");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));

    // Read the file
    readfile($path);

    // Return true:
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE 16.05.2023**

Thanks to the assistance provided in the comment section, we have made progress in identifying the issue. It has been determined that when the file is downloaded, additional information is added to the file. Specifically, a leading whitespace is consistently included in all downloaded files. Interestingly, the PDF format appears to be able to disregard this extra information, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: What is the error you're having? Btw, someone can download just about any file from your webserver, inside or outside webroot, through your script.

Comment: @SalmanA Actually the OP prepends a path to the passed file path, so downloading is somewhat restricted.

Comment: `../../../.htaccess`

Comment: @SalmanA Thank you for bringing the vulnerability to my attention. I will make a quick fix for it for now. 

Unfortunately, there are no visible errors apart from that the png and jpg images appear corrupt. It seems that when the file is set as inline instead of an attachment, Firefox cannot load it due to occurring errors. However, there are currently no other issues to report

Comment: Have you considered testing with multiple file types and mime types to see if the fact that you get the application headers is actually a fluke? eg. create a directory with a curated list of files, and the expected mime type and run it with postman to see that the downloads are correct?

Comment: @ere "corrupt", open the file in hex editor. May be some php warning or error becomes part of the file. The of course there is utf BOM that could have been added by your code editor.

Comment: Most likely there is something output before the actual file content. It doesn't affect PDFs because most PDF viewers skip garbage at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @SalmanA, you were correct! There appears to be a leading "whitespace" in the downloaded file. By removing it using a HEX editor, the file becomes "non-corrupt" (apologies if I misused the term "corrupt"). I compared the original, uploaded, and downloaded files; an alteration occurred during the download process. My next step is to investigate the cause of this additional space. To provide context, the original file's first byte was `FFD8FFE0`, whereas the downloaded file's first was `0AFFD8FF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your PHP script is adding a LF character (line feed, Unix line ending character, `0x0A`). This could be caused by having a blank line somewhere in your script for example:

```
<?php
echo "ABCD";
# the output of this program will be 0D 0A 41 42 43 44
# or 0A 41 42 43 44 depending on line ending used
```

Locate the blank line and remove it.

> To provide context, the original file's first byte was `FFD8FFE0`,
> whereas the downloaded file's first was `0AFFD8FF`

`FFD8FFE0` are the first four bytes of a JPEG image ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)); you seem to have `0AFFD8FFE0` in the beginning where the 0A is the LF character.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The solution in the comment section got me to the issue. Also thank you for noting the vulnerability. I will get that fixed too.